# No external network on Ubuntu 9.10, though DNS works

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

I have a weird problem I can't solve. I have several computers, two with [Xubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu) 9.10.
One of them, acting as a media server, has stopped to work when it comes to external networking. I can do for example:

```
ping google.com
```

Which gives me an IP adress back, like:

```
name@Media:/etc$ ping google.com
PING google.com (66.102.9.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

That tells me it reaches the DNS? But I get no response at all. If I ping a local computer all works fine. I can also reach the computer via SSH without any problems. I have always used [NetworkManager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager), but now I uninstalled it and made the settings manually like this:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.52
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Still no luck. I have no specific settings for this one in my router, and all the other computers, including my Windows laptop works fine. This is very annoying since I can't even do an update or anything..

The output from `ifconfig` looks like this:

```
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:1d:9f:10:89
          inet addr:192.168.1.52  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:1dff:fe9f:1089/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15410 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1167398 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:694973 (694.9 KB)
          Interrupt:27 Base address:0xe000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2150 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2150 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:143456 (143.4 KB)  TX bytes:143456 (143.4 KB)
```

The output from `route -n` like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

I do not know where the adress starting with 169.254 comes from. Could that be a part of the problem?

I am hoping for some assistance since I'm totally stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Tracepath gives me this:

```
user@Media:/etc$ tracepath google.com
 1:  Media (192.168.1.52)                                   0.126 ms pmtu 1500
 1:  Router (192.168.1.1)                                   1.209 ms
 1:  Router (192.168.1.1)                                   1.010 ms
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
```

It seems like the router anyway? Or how am I supposed to understand this?

Sorry, I got some formatting issues here. It was very hard to read the code when I used the comment fielt, no formatting options. So I answer my self instead. Hope it's OK.

Comment: welcome to Super User!  this is not a traditional threaded forum so you need to add info like this by editing your original post.  use the little gray "edit" link at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tracepath www.google.com` and see what that gives you; you should see where the connection breaks down.